# Copy file from client node to workstation

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to copy a file from chef client to chef workstation.The `remote_file` resource copies a file from a remote location onto chef client . How can we copy a file from chef client to chef workstation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely not how Chef works. You cannot access any workstation through Chef.